# Where can I find updated and "unbloated" webapp archetypes for maven?

Tags: maven

I'm pretty new to maven and I'm trying to find a good archetype for creating a webapp "starting point" for a Spring MVC project. I have been rtfm-ing, googling and installed many of the archetypes I've found in lists presented here on SO and other places, but I never found one fitting my needs.

- Example 1: I installed org.apache.maven.archetypes -
  maven-archetype-webapp, but it seems outdated, as it uses JRE 1.5,
  JUnit 3.8.1 and also it's missing src/test/java, src/test/resources
  and src/main/resources by default.
- Example 2: Using eclipse, I created a new "Spring MVC Project" from "Spring Template
  Project", which also set up Maven for me, but it installs loads of
  stuff I'm not sure I even need.

I also tried some other archetypes, like from AppFuse and Cocoon, but the "bloating" in their basic webapp archetypes was even worse.

*What I'm after is kind of what the maven-archetype-webapp is giving me, but an "updated" version that also includes the test and resource directories.*

**So I guess my question is two folded:**

**1. Is there an "updated" version of the maven-archetype-webapp archetype?**

...and/or...

**2. Is there a way for me, as a maven newbie, to create my own archetype that fits my needs?**

... or have I totally been misunderstanding the concept of archetypes?

Comment: Did you find a satisfying solution for this problem? Even now I am struggling with 1.5/2.3 default settings and missing directories... My first attempt at hacking it to 1.8/3.1 broke my testproject. (;

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to run JDK 1.8 and the Dynamic Web Module 3.0 (in Eclipse).

First JDK 1.5: Eclipse m2e plugin may be the culprit for the JDK version, as it defaults the JRE system library to 1.5. You need to tell maven to set the correct Java System library --> go [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) and snip that <build>-tag and use version 1.8 to do that.

See next comment for the Dynamic Web Module Version...

Comment: Secondly the Dynamic Web Module version: you need to add the correct Dynamic Web Module version to your project. You can do that by going to the menu project > properties > Project Facets. Here you can select what version of the DWM you want to use and then click ok.

Comment: I solved it by simply creating a new Maven project, using maven-compiler-plugin to correctly set the used JVM/compiler level to 1.8, added servlet-api 3.1.0 as dependency and set maven <packaging> to war. After a maven refresh everything works perfectly and even the Facets (DWM,Java and JS) are set correctly. If you don't set packaging to war the Facets aren't autoconfigured. You can then add the web.xml manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an "updated" version of the maven-archetype-webapp archetype?

AFAIK, version 1.0 is the last version (and is not very up-to-date). BTW, it seems it doesn't define the source code level (so I guess 1.5 you have is coming from your IDE)

> Is there a way for me, as a maven newbie, to create my own archetype that fits my needs?

Creating a new artifact is quite simple. [Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) are the details.

*Is it so simple for a maven newbie ?* Well, it depends... but according the quality of your post, it seems you understood the basics so yes, it should be easy to do.

Basically an archetype is nothing more than:

- the target project structure you need (with some files like pom.xml, web.xml, ...)
- a file describing the resources that need to be included in this structure.

Take a look at maven-archetype-webapp-1.0.jar (i.e. unzip it) and you will immediately understand why the directories are missing and from where junit-3.8.1 comes from.

Note: you will find the maven-archetype-webapp-1.0.jar in your maven repository. (Probably here : /.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/artifacts/maven-archetype-webapp/1.0/... but I didn't check)

Comment: Strange that it set the source code level to 1.5, I have it set to 1.7 in Eclipse and have never even used 1.5.
However, the link you posted is exactly what I'm looking for (provided I find no suitable ready made basic archetype). I'm surprised I did not find it myself, as I was actually searching for it on the apache site.
I think I will manage to create a suitable archetype of my own, given the information in that guide. Thanks, ben75!